# How override moment now time with wrapper module

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am using moment and need to stub current time to always return 1/1/18 for example. So when I call `moment()` or `moment.now()` I should receive a moment object with the time set to 1/1/18.

Now I could override [moment.now](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/now/) but then anything else that uses moment will have this stub due to module caching, which is not what I want.

So I have wrote a momentWrapper that copies moment's protoypes and defines a new constructor. The problem is when calling `moment()` it doesn't use the new defined prototype for `now`, as I'm simply calling moment's constructor. I need to copy moment and change it's `now` protoype in my new consturctor I'm just not sure how to do that.

This is what I have so far:

```
/**
 * Wraps moment so that alternate time can be set as the 'now' time.
 * This idea was grabbed from fs-extra https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra
 * @module lib/momentWrapper
 */

var moment = require('moment');

function momentWrapper() {
  return moment.apply(this, arguments);
}

assign(momentWrapper, moment);

momentWrapper.prototype = Object.create(moment.prototype);
momentWrapper.prototype.now = newNow;
momentWrapper.prototype.constructor = momentWrapper;

function newNow() {
  return +new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');
}

/**
 * Loops through given arguments and assigns them to a object
 * Credit: fs-extra https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/fab376ec2bd4d4420806644c1b37a7ac487d17ec/lib/util/assign.js
 * @function assign
 * @return {Object} Mutated object with copied keys
 */
function assign () {
  const args = [].slice.call(arguments).filter(i => i);
  const dest = args.shift();
  args.forEach(src => {
    Object.keys(src).forEach(key => {
        if (key === 'now') {
          dest[key] = newNow;
        }
        else {
          dest[key] = src[key];
        }
    });
  });

  return dest;
}

module.exports = momentWrapper;
```

Testing file:

```
var momentWrapper = require('./momentWrapper');
var moment = require('moment');


console.log(momentWrapper()); // Not working
console.log(momentWrapper('12/25/18', 'MM/DD/YY')); // Working
console.log(momentWrapper(momentWrapper.now()).format()) // Working

console.log('----------------------------------------');

console.log(moment()); // Working not being overridden
console.log(moment(moment.now()).format()) // // Working not being overridden
```

Output:

```
moment("2018-01-27T15:56:50.928")
moment("2018-12-25T00:00:00.000")
1995-12-17T03:24:00-05:00
----------------------------------------
moment("2018-01-27T15:56:50.938")
2018-01-27T15:56:50-05:00
```

Comment: Perhaps this may be of use – http://dancork.co.uk/2015/12/07/stubbing-moment/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, rather than using a wrapper; you could temporarily replace the `now` function with a custom stub and when you're finished using it, just put the original one back.

```
var moment = require("moment");

// prepare before testing

moment.originalNow = moment.now;
moment.now = () => +new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');

console.log([
    moment().format(), 
    moment(moment.now()).format(), 
    moment('12/25/18', 'MM/DD/YY').format()
]);

// clean after testing

moment.now = moment.originalNow;
moment.originalNow = undefined;

console.log([
    moment().format(), 
    moment(moment.now()).format()
]);
```

Comment: That won't work for me I want to be able to use the stubbed moment (in a wrapper) and regular moment at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Its so obvious that i havent seen it. You dont even need to play with inheritance, just clone the moment object and rewrite the now property:

```
  const orig = require("moment");

  const moment = (...args) => args.length === 0 ? moment.now() : orig(...args);

  Object.assign(moment, orig);

  moment.now = () => orig('1995-12-17T03:24:00');

  export moment;
```

Comment: I copy and pasted those, changes ran by sample code and I don't see any changes/it's not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: @alexander oh right, you brought me onto the inheritance track and i did not notice. You dont even need inheritance...

Comment: Can you show me a sample test file with this? Maybe I'm doing something wrong but that doesn't seem to be working for me either.

Comment: Try `console`ing `moment()` and that will not work. Also that is overridding moment which I don't want to do.

Comment: @alexander Nope it is not. Logging `moment` will log a moment object as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164016/discussion-between-alexander-lallier-and-jonas-w).